# Has the Cocoapod of J2ObjC been depricated?

Tags: cocoapods, j2objc

The [J2Objc Cocoapods page](https://cocoapods.org/pods/J2ObjC) lists the latest version as 0.9.6.1 and this is what `pod update` fetches.  However, the [J2Objc git page](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases) indicates that the latest version is 2.0.2.

*Has the Cocoapod for J2ObjC been deprecated?*

Answer (score 1):

The J2ObjC Cocoapod was created and maintained by external developers who use j2objc in their projects, but who are not members of the J2ObjC team. I suggest directly contacting the people on the pod's "Maintained by" links on the podspec page as to its status.

Since it's open-source you can also make the change yourself and send it to them to update the pod. I'm not a Cocoapods user, but it looks like all that's needed is to change the version and source tag in the [J2ObjC.podspec.json file](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/c/1/9/J2ObjC/0.9.6.1/J2ObjC.podspec.json), though updating the minimum platforms to iOS 10 and macOS 10.11 would be good to do, too.

Comment: Do you ever plan to?  Google releases other libraries (like maps) as a Pod.

Comment: I've found a J2ObjC pod that works quite well with our project here: https://github.com/dough-com/J2ObjC-Pod
Fork, update the version number if desired and you are all set.